# Excel file into Text file conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an Execl file. I want to convert it into a text file. Is it possible in SQL Server?

Comment: Convert to text file ? SQL Server is not a file format converter

Comment: This should be nothing to do with SQL Server. Why not use "Save As" in Excel and choose a text file format?

Comment: On daily basis we are getting files.......Daily we can't do it ....

Comment: Is the text file your final end result?  Or do you want to convert the text file to something else after that?

Comment: Text file is final result

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you get the excels on daily basis; why don't you create an SSIS task which will take all the files from a particular location where all these excels are dumped and convert it through a DFT. You can then schedule this package on SQL server agent to run on regular basis.

P.S. I am assuming you're familiar with SSIS.